# can't access the xib file?

Tags: iphone, xib

Initially I created UITableViewController class without xib file but now i need Xib file for some action on tableView. here i can't link the new created xib file with UITableViewController Class. please help me for this issue. how can i make the link between xib and class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just drag the tableview from library and link with class i got the solution

Thanks for the help